# I want to split a file into equally sized "chunks", or slices and use goroutines to process them simultaneously

Tags: go, goroutine

Using Go, I have large log files. Currently I open them, create a new scanner `bufio.NewScanner`, and then `for scanner.Scan()` to loop through the lines. Each line is sent through a processing function, which matches it to regular expressions and extracts data. I would like to process this file in chunks simultaneously using goroutines. I believe this may be quicker than looping through the whole file sequentially.

It can take a few seconds per file, and I'm wondering if I can process a single file in, say, 10 pieces at a time. I believe I can sacrifice the memory if needed. I have ~3gb, and the biggest log file is maybe 75mb.

I see that a `scanner` has a `.Split()` method, where you can provide a custom split function, but I wasn't able to find a good solution using this method.

I've also tried creating a slice of slices, looping through the scanner with `scanner.Scan()` and appending `scanner.Text()` to each slice.
eg:

```
// pseudocode because I couldn't get this to work either

scanner := bufio.NewScanner(logInfo)
threads := [[], [], [], [], []]

i := 0
for scanner.Scan() {
    i = i + 1
    if i > 5 {
        i = 0
    }
    threads[i] = append(threads[i], scanner.Text())
}
fmt.Println(threads)
```

I'm new to Go and concerned about efficiency and performance. I want to learn how to write good Go code! Any help or advice is really appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to preserve the input order?

Comment: @Peter No, order shouldn't matter in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Peter gives a good starting point, if you wanted to do something like a fan-out, fan-in pattern you could do something like:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    file, err := os.Open("/path/to/file.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    lines := make(chan string)
    // start four workers to do the heavy lifting
    wc1 := startWorker(lines)
    wc2 := startWorker(lines)
    wc3 := startWorker(lines)
    wc4 := startWorker(lines)
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    go func() {
        defer close(lines)
        for scanner.Scan() {
            lines <- scanner.Text()
        }

        if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }()

    merged := merge(wc1, wc2, wc3, wc4)
    for line := range merged {
        fmt.Println(line)
    }
}

func startWorker(lines <-chan string) <-chan string {
    finished := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        defer close(finished)
        for line := range lines {
            // Do your heavy work here
            finished <- line
        }
    }()
    return finished
}

func merge(cs ...<-chan string) <-chan string {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    out := make(chan string)

    // Start an output goroutine for each input channel in cs.  output
    // copies values from c to out until c is closed, then calls wg.Done.
    output := func(c <-chan string) {
        for n := range c {
            out <- n
        }
        wg.Done()
    }
    wg.Add(len(cs))
    for _, c := range cs {
        go output(c)
    }

    // Start a goroutine to close out once all the output goroutines are
    // done.  This must start after the wg.Add call.
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(out)
    }()
    return out
}
```

Comment: This is very interesting how involved this is. Not quite like other languages I'm used to!

Thank you for the thorough example, it really helped me dig deeper into this!

Comment: Sending each line will create an unnecessary contention. Instead, batch them together in groups, then send. Channel communication is not free.

Comment: @InancGumus - What if the single goroutine that reads lines from `/path/to/file.txt` imposes a bottleneck? How could I use multiple readers on a single file? Any ideas?

Comment: @Shuzheng The thing is whenever you communicate through channels you're paying a synchronization cost unless (*sometimes*) you're using unbuffered chans.

Comment: I'm new to Go but for me this isn't working.  The first wc1 ends up processing almost all the lines, but wc2, wc3 and wc4 only process a single line each.

Answer (score 2):

If it is acceptable that line N+1 is processed before line N, you can use a simple fan-out pattern to get started. [The Go blog](https://blog.golang.org/pipelines) explains this and more advanced patterns, such as cancelation and fan-in.

Note that this is just a starting point to keep it simple and on point. You would almost certainly want to wait for the `process` functions to return before exiting, for instance. This is explained in the mentioned blog post.

```
package main

import "bufio"

func main() {
    var sc *bufio.Scanner

    lines := make(chan string)

    go process(lines)
    go process(lines)
    go process(lines)
    go process(lines)

    for sc.Scan() {
            lines <- sc.Text()
    }

    close(lines)
}

func process(lines <-chan string) {
    for line := range lines {
            // implement processing here
    }
}
```